# Метки [reflection] или [рефлексия]?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть [reflection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) и [рефлексия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f). Нужно синонимизировать.

Вот только, у нас часто оставляют ру вариант метки, а en синонимизируют. Но с меткой [рефлексия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f) 8 вопросов, а с [reflection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) 118.

**UPD:** тогда надо синонимизировать en метку к русской.

Comment: Учим всех русскому и синонимизируем к нему же!

Comment: Я не вижу простора для обсуждения и демократии. Эдак, чего доброго, кто-то проголосует за оставить вопросы с английской меткой. Вопросы переносим на правильную метку (русскую), чтобы не смущать будущие поколения неправильными метками, сто вопросов -- это не так уж и много.

Comment: О, прикольно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/72/synonymizer?userid=178988

Comment: @Qwertiy с посвящением =D

Comment: @alexolut, рефлексия - это всё равно не по-русски. Вот в некоторых источниках на ИТ-тематику слово reflection переводят напрямую - отражение.

Comment: @Qwertiy там еще [галочка кривая](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287196/339911)

Comment: @mymedia хорошо, что мы не они.

Comment: Ни разу не слышал, чтоб рефлексию называли отражением в проф. среде =/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Синонимизировал, основная метка [рефлексия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Comment: @Suvitruf, ой))) Спасибо! :)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста ^_^"